# Connecting two device over Wi-fi using sockets

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

I have written code for server and client sockets.
I have used threads using handler.But it often gives exception that **Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views**
How to manage to manage this?

Here is the code for Server Socket

```
 public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() { 
        try {
            Looper.prepare();
            if (SERVERIP != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                    }
                });
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress().toString()
                , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                serverStatus.append("\n"+serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());
                while (true) {
                    // listen for incoming clients
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

                            serverStatus.setText("Connected.");


                    try {
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                }
                            }); 
                        }
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                            }
                        });
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    serverStatus.setText("Error"+e.getMessage());

                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Code for client Socket

```
  public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 8080);
            connected = true;

                try {
                    console.append("\nC: Sending command.");
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                .getOutputStream())), true);
                        // where you issue the commands
                        out.println("Hey Server!");
                        console.append("C: Sent.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    console.append("S: Error= "+ e.getMessage());
                }

            socket.close();
            console.append("\nC: Closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Client :", e.getMessage());

            //console.append("\nC: Error= ");
            connected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here console is the text view where i am trying to put some messages.
I can see messages in the log but not on the text view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views How to manage to manage this?

Use [`runOnUiThread()`](http://goo.gl/hUjKR). Or, use a `Handler`. Or, use [`post()`](http://goo.gl/eHkYR).

Comment: I have used handler.i m not sure if I have used it right.can u post some sample code for handler where UI therad is modified from some other thread.

Comment: @Nilesh Tupe: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Threads/Handler

Comment: Please suggest correction in my code or give some comment over it so that I can better understand what I have to do.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can two android devices interact peer to peer using sockets without any network?

Comment: @zIronManBox: If they support WifiDirect, yes.